# Jquery/javascript object duplicate value from each() function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 3 `input[name=alc_val]`
I am trying to get their value in object.
I did this:

```
var alc_val = new Array();
$("input[name=alc_val]").each(function(i){
    alc_val[i]= $(this).val();
});

console.log(alc_val);
```

- I expected this: `["111", "111", "111"]`
- I found this: `["111", "111", "111", "111", "111", "111"]`

Why is it so and how can I get the expected output?

Comment: Can you create a fiddle that demonstrates the problem? For example, [this](http://jsfiddle.net/40L5s4Lu/) seems to work just fine.

Comment: Most likely you have six `input[name=alc_val]`s

Answer (score 1):

I have reproduce the scenario here : http://jsfiddle.net/u8juqycz/

```
<input name="alc_val" value="test1"/>
<input name="alc_val" value="test2"/>
<input name="alc_val" value="test3"/>

var alc_val = new Array();
$("input[name=alc_val]").each(function(i){
    alc_val[i]= $(this).val();
});

console.log(alc_val);
```

It works. So you must have more than 3 textbox

Comment: surprising.. I do have just 3 of this fields but JS is counting 6. I have no idea why.

Answer (score 0):

It is working here : [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/miike21/d8jdkeox/1/)
Maybe you have 6 input instead.

---

Html

```
<input name="alc_val" value="111">
<input name="alc_val" value="111">
<input name="alc_val" value="111">
```

---

Js

```
var alc_val = new Array();
$("input[name=alc_val]").each(function(i){
  alc_val[i]= $(this).val();
});

console.log(alc_val);
```